# Using future perfect vs future perfect continuous

Tags: differences, future, perfect-aspect

What's the difference between these two sentences:

> By the time he come back home, she will have worked for 45 minutes.

and

> By the time he come back home, she will been working for 45 minutes.

I think the first one is incorrect and we should use the second one.

Comment: Both sentences are ungrammatical. The verb in the first clause in both sentences should be _comes_, which is the correct present tense form, not _come_. The second one is also ungrammatical because the auxiliary _have_ is missing between _will_ and _been_. I would say that you should work more on the present tense and on auxiliary verbs before you attempt such heights as the future perfect continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at this again, I am guessing that the omission of "have" is a typo, and the question is simply, is the future perfect or the future perfect progressive correct. Your first example is future perfect, which is used to express an action that will be completed before some other future action or condition; the second example is future perfect progressive, which expresses a continuous action that will be completed at some point in the future. In many cases, both are acceptable. However, the perfect tense allows the possibility or perhaps even implies that her 45 minutes of work will have been completed before he comes homes, while the progressive more clearly indicates that her work will be ongoing when he arrives.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is almost correct. It should be "by the time he come*s* back home, she will have worked for 45 minutes." This is the future progressive tense, used to express a continuous action that will be completed at some point in the future. The second one, without the "have," is not correct under any circumstance. It is also possible to say "By the time he comes back home, she will have worked for 45 minutes." This is the future perfect.

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to decide between

```
 ...she will have worked 45 minutes.
```

and

```
...she will have been working for 45 minutes.
```

The choice depends entirely on what you mean. If she will have worked *continuously*, use the continuous aspect.